How can I use stored procedures in Django with MySQL and run 'python manage.py migrate' without issues?
Context:
I'm working on a project using Django with the Django REST framework to build an API. My database is MySQL, and I'm using XAMPP as my local development environment.
Problem:
I need to use stored procedures in my Django application to perform specific operations in my MySQL database. However, I'm facing difficulties integrating the stored procedures with Django, and I'm also experiencing issues when running python manage.py migrate.
Additional Details:

I have created stored procedures directly in my MySQL database using phpMyAdmin.
I'm using Django's ORM to interact with the database in other parts of my application.
I would like to be able to call the stored procedures from my Django application and run python manage.py migrate without errors to ensure that my database is properly synchronized with Django's models.

Relevant Files and Code:



file
description




utils.py
File containing the calls to the stored procedures.


models.py
File where I define Django models representing my database schema.



Questions:

What is the best way to use stored procedures in Django, particularly with a MySQL database?
How can I ensure that the stored procedures are compatible with Django's migration process (python manage.py migrate)?
Are there any special considerations I should be aware of when working with stored procedures in Django?

Any guidance or practical examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
After execute this command y get the next result:
python manage.py migrate
result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 71, in callproc
    return self.cursor.callproc(procname)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 322, in callproc
    self._query(q)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 330, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 261, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'bazar.apirest_sale' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josaf\Documents\School\BazarAdmin\APIRestHNP\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\josaf\Documents\School\BazarAdmin\APIRestHNP\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 107, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 100, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 519, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\josaf\Documents\School\BazarAdmin\APIRestHNP\APIRestHNP\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path("BAZARAPI/", include("APIRest.urls")),
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 39, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\josaf\Documents\School\BazarAdmin\APIRestHNP\APIRest\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .views import *
  File "C:\Users\josaf\Documents\School\BazarAdmin\APIRestHNP\APIRest\views.py", line 20, in <module>
    class SalesLastWeekAmountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  File "C:\Users\josaf\Documents\School\BazarAdmin\APIRestHNP\APIRest\views.py", line 21, in SalesLastWeekAmountViewSet
    queryset = callSalesLastWeekAmount()
  File "C:\Users\josaf\Documents\School\BazarAdmin\APIRestHNP\APIRest\utils.py", line 5, in callSalesLastWeekAmount
    cursor.callproc('SalesLastWeekAmount')
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 69, in callproc
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 71, in callproc
    return self.cursor.callproc(procname)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 322, in callproc
    self._query(q)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 330, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\josaf\anaconda3\envs\HNP-Env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 261, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'bazar.apirest_sale' doesn't exist")

Utils.py
from django.db import connection

def callSalesLastWeekAmount():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesLastWeekAmount')
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def callSalesLastWeekQuantity():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesLastWeekQuantity')
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def callSalesLastWeekAmountSeller(seller):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesLastWeekAmountSeller', [seller])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def callSalesLastWeekQuantitySeller(seller):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesLastWeekQuantitySeller', [seller])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def callSalesDateRangeAmount(date_start, date_end):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesDateRangeAmount', [date_start, date_end])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def callSalesDateRangeQuantity(date_start, date_end):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesDateRangeQuantity', [date_start, date_end])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def callSalesDateRangeSellerAmount(date_start, date_end, seller):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesDateRangeSellerAmount', [date_start, date_end, seller])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def callSalesDateRangeSellerQuantity(date_start, date_end, seller):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('SalesDateRangeSellerQuantity', [seller, date_start, date_end])
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result

models.py

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ventas_semana = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "username": self.username,
            "password": self.password,
            "email": self.email,
            "ventas_semana": self.ventas_semana,
            "is_superuser": self.is_superuser,
            "is_active": self.is_active
        }
        
class Sale(models.Model):
    #insertar campos
    sale_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, default=None, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def as_dict(self):
        return { 
                "amount": self.amount,
                "user_id": self.user_id.id,
                "quantity": self.quantity,
                "date": self.date,
                "sale_id": self.sale_id,
                "is_active": self.is_active
                }

views.py

from .utils import *
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    
class VentaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sale.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer

#================= Estadisticas =======================

class SalesLastWeekAmountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = callSalesLastWeekAmount()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer

class SalesLastWeekQuantityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = callSalesLastWeekQuantity()
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer
    
class SalesLastWeekQuantitySellerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Obtén el ID del query de la URL
        query_id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        # Ahora puedes utilizar este ID en tu función de consulta
        queryset = callSalesLastWeekQuantitySeller(query_id)
        return queryset
    
class SalesLastWeekAmountSellerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Obtén el ID del query de la URL
        query_id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        # Ahora puedes utilizar este ID en tu función de consulta
        queryset = callSalesLastWeekAmountSeller(query_id)
        return queryset
    
class SalesDateRangeQuantityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Obtén el ID del query de la URL
        query_start_date = self.kwargs.get('star_date')
        query_end_date = self.kwargs.get('end_date')
        # Ahora puedes utilizar este ID en tu función de consulta
        queryset = callSalesDateRangeQuantity(query_start_date, query_end_date)
        return queryset
    
class SalesDateRangeAmountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Obtén el ID del query de la URL
        query_start_date = self.kwargs.get('star_date')
        query_end_date = self.kwargs.get('end_date')
        
        # Ahora puedes utilizar este ID en tu función de consulta
        queryset = callSalesDateRangeAmount(query_start_date, query_end_date)
        return queryset
    
class SalesDateRangeSellerQuantityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Obtén el ID del query de la URL
        query_id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        query_start_date = self.kwargs.get('star_date')
        query_end_date = self.kwargs.get('end_date')
        
        # Ahora puedes utilizar este ID en tu función de consulta
        queryset = callSalesDateRangeSellerQuantity(query_start_date, query_end_date, query_id)
        return queryset
    
class SalesDateRangeSellerAmountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = VentaSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Obtén el ID del query de la URL
        query_id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        query_start_date = self.kwargs.get('star_date')
        query_end_date = self.kwargs.get('end_date')
        
        # Ahora puedes utilizar este ID en tu función de consulta
        queryset = callSalesDateRangeSellerAmount(query_start_date, query_end_date, query_id)
        return queryset


SQL PROCEDURES

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesDateRangeSellerAmount$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesDateRangeSellerAmount(IN start_date DATE, IN end_date DATE, IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(amount) as day_amount, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    AND user_id_id = user_id
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);
END$$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesDateRangeSellerQuantity$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesDateRangeSellerQuantity(IN start_date DATE, IN end_date DATE, IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(quantity) as day_quantity, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    AND user_id_id = user_id
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);
END$$

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesDateRangeAmount$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesDateRangeAmount(IN start_date DATE, IN end_date DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(amount) as day_amount, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);
END$$

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesDateRangeQuantity$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesDateRangeQuantity(IN start_date DATE, IN end_date DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(quantity) as day_quantity, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);
END$$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesLastWeekAmountSeller$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesLastWeekAmountSeller(IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(amount) as day_amount, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    AND user_id_id = user_id
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);
END$$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesLastWeekQuantitySeller$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesLastWeekQuantitySeller(IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(quantity) as day_quantity, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    AND user_id_id = user_id
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);
END$$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesLastWeekAmount$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesLastWeekAmount()
    
BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(amount) as day_amount, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);
    
END$$


DELIMITER ;



DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SalesLastWeekQuantity$$

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesLastWeekQuantity()

BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(quantity) as day_quantity, DATE(date) AS day
    FROM apirest_sale
    WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    AND is_active = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(date);

END$$

DELIMITER ;



Stored procedures defined in Django...Why not the post_save() signal? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/signals/#post-save
